# how to run bash script inside the PBS script in the head node, after running the program in compute nodes

Tags: bash, ssh, hpc, pbs, qsub

### current working script (script-A)

```
  #!/bin/bash 
  #PBS -N test7 
  #PBS -q batch 
  #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=6,walltime=00:30:00 
  #PBS -j oe 
  cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR 

mpirun -np 6 /home/sai/1QE/qe-6.5/bin/pw.x  < si.scf.in > 92scf.out<br>
```

### What I want?

I want to run a "bash script analysis.sh" in the "HEAD NODE" after running the above job inside the compute node.

### e.g. script-B

```
  #!/bin/bash 
  #PBS -N test7 
  #PBS -q batch 
  #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=6,walltime=00:30:00 
  #PBS -j oe 
  cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR 

mpirun -np 6 /home/sai/1QE/qe-6.5/bin/pw.x  < si.scf.in > 92scf.out

bash analysis.sh
```

### Problem

The above script-B is also fine, but not in my case.

my problem is the analysis program is installed only in my head node, not in the compute node.
so it will work only in the head node.

so, is there ant way to run the analysis.sh script in the head node after PBS script in the compute node.

Comment: Please format the question properly (use code blocks)

Comment: Wait for the job to finish and then run your analysis script on the frontend. The job files that you submit to PBS always run on one of the allocated compute nodes. You can enable notification by email when your job has finished with `#PBS -m e` and `#PBS -M youremail@domain.com` so you don't have to constantly run `qstat`.

Comment: Another option, provided that compute nodes are allowed to make SSH connections to the head, is to create a passwordless SSH key that allows you to login into the head and repalce `bash analysis.sh` with `ssh youruser@headnode "cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR && bash analysis.sh"`. You'll need to add the run time of the analysis script to the job walltime requirement. Speak with your cluster admins first, though. Look up "passwordless SSH" in your favourite Internet search engine for more information.

Comment: thank you @HristoIliev I appreciate your help:)
but I will go with #PBS -M youremail@domain.com.
and then manually run the bash analysis.sh

actually I have multiple analyses.sh files that may again take time for every new project on creating SSH keys.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a possibility in the PBS script to exit from the compute nodes after the calculation and then run all my analysis bash files.

but it seems not possible.

anyway thanks again I will definitely use your 2nd suggestion with a passwordless SSH key. :)

Comment: This is not how PBS works. You cannot simply exit a job script and continue it on the submit host. Job scripts get spooled and then dispatched to a compute node. What you can do though is submit your job script as an interactive job and then `qsub` will wait until the job is finished, so you can have a script that calls `qsub -I -x script-A` and then runs the analysis. Again, check with your admins if that's OK.

Comment: @HristoIliev thank you so much. it is working.
I am really sorry for my late reply, But Thank you a ton:)

Comment: @sal care to describe in detail your actual solution as an answer and accept it? It may help someone else in a similar situation.